# Testnet seem to not support Corda4 with SignatureConstraint

Tags: corda

I build Corda4 with SignatureConstraint and deploy with Testnet. Then when I make transaction I got this exception

```
net.corda.core.node.ZoneVersionTooLowException: Signature constraints requires all nodes on the Corda compatibility zone to be running at least platform version 4. The current zone is only enforcing a minimum platform version of 1. Please contact your zone operator.
    at net.corda.core.internal.CordaUtilsKt.checkMinimumPlatformVersion(CordaUtils.kt:36) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.Verifier.verifyConstraints(TransactionVerifierServiceInternal.kt:332) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.Verifier.verify(TransactionVerifierServiceInternal.kt:61) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:125) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addMissingDependency(TransactionBuilder.kt:173) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:160) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core$default(TransactionBuilder.kt:128) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:125) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toLedgerTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:451) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:459) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows.CustomerIssueFlow.call(CustomerIssueFlow.kt:166) ~[cordapp-flows-1.0.jar:?]
    at th.co.jventures.ddlp.cordapp.flows.CustomerIssueFlow.call(CustomerIssueFlow.kt:32) ~[cordapp-flows-1.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:228) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
```

Is this mean Testnet not support Signature constraint right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Corda Testnet is minimum platform version 1 at this time. There is a new Testnet with a minimum platform version of 4 coming out in due course that will support Corda V4 and therefore signature constraints.

Source: I am the tech lead of the R3 Corda Testnet.

Comment: Any near expected date for its release?

Comment: I have since left R3 - worth asking on their public Slack and reporting back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing and want to debug, Mock network also doesn't support V4, so you will not be able to mock it either.

An alternative is to run nodes locally and attach the debugger with Corda's node driver as explained at **https://docs.corda.net/debugging-a-cordapp.html**

This is how I enabled on mock tests:

```
 HashSet<TestCordapp> cordapps = new HashSet<>(asList( TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.money"),
            TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts"),
            TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows")));

        List<String> packages = Arrays.asList("[your packages]");

        #Create new drive parameters and generate new network parameters copying defult
        # except the minimun supported version
        DriverParameters driverParameters = new DriverParameters().withIsDebug(true).withCordappsForAllNodes(cordapps);
        NetworkParameters networkParameters = driverParameters.getNetworkParameters();
        NetworkParameters parameters = networkParameters.copy(4, networkParameters.getNotaries(), networkParameters.getMaxMessageSize(), networkParameters.getMaxTransactionSize(), networkParameters.getModifiedTime(), networkParameters.getEpoch(), networkParameters.getWhitelistedContractImplementations());

        InMemoryMessagingNetwork.ServicePeerAllocationStrategy servicePeerAllocationStrategy = new InMemoryMessagingNetwork.ServicePeerAllocationStrategy.Random();
        MockNetworkParameters mockNetworkParameters = new MockNetworkParameters(cordapps);
        MockNetworkNotarySpec mockNetworkNotarySpec = new MockNetworkNotarySpec(new CordaX500Name("Notary", "London", "GB"), false);
        mockNet =  new MockNetwork(packages,mockNetworkParameters,false,false,servicePeerAllocationStrategy,Arrays.asList(mockNetworkNotarySpec),parameters);
        issuerNode = mockNet.createNode(new CordaX500Name("Issuer", "London", "GB"));

        issuer = issuerNode.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0);
```