# ZoneVersionTooLowException when working with MockNetwork

Tags: corda

cordaVersion = 4.3

tokens_release_version = '1.1-RC06-PRESIGN'

OS = Windows 10

Using a MockNetwork I was testing TokenPointer’s that point to EvolvableTokenType’s (reference states) using the TokenSDK when I got the following error message:

net.corda.core.node.ZoneVersionTooLowException: Reference states requires all nodes on the Corda compatibility zone to be running at least platform version 4. The current zone is only enforcing a minimum platform version of 1. Please contact your zone operator.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same `ZoneVersionTooLowException` error when using reference states in my contract and testing the flows using `MockNetwork`.

I fixed it by changing the `minimumPlatformVersion` to 4 in the `testNetworkParameters` class and using that to construct my `MockNetwork`. Here is the snippet in Kotlin.

```
import net.corda.testing.common.internal.testNetworkParameters

class AssetCreationFlowTests {
    private lateinit var network: MockNetwork
    private lateinit var a: StartedMockNode
    private lateinit var b: StartedMockNode

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val myNetworkParameters = testNetworkParameters(minimumPlatformVersion = 4)

        network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(
                cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
                        TestCordapp.findCordapp(AssetContract::class.packageName)
                ),
                networkParameters = myNetworkParameters
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked on stackoverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332803/testnet-seem-to-not-support-corda4-with-signatureconstraint) but I was determined to get a MockNetwork working because it is so handy for testing.

I had to create my MockNetwork manually versus using the defaults.  I extracted all the MockNetwork properties from a default build of a MockNetwork:

`MockNetwork mockNet = new MockNetwork(new MockNetworkParameters(getTestCordapps()));`

Step 1) Build a NetworkParameters object setting the minimumPlatformVersion to 4:

```
List<NotaryInfo> notaryinfo = Arrays.asList();

NetworkParameters networkParameters = new NetworkParameters(
    4,
    notaryinfo,
    10485760,
    524288000,
    java.time.Instant.now(),
    1,
    Collections.emptyMap()
);
```

Step 2) Create a MockNetworkParameters object using the new NetworkParameters;

```
MockNetworkParameters mockNetworkParameters = new MockNetworkParameters(
    false,
    false,
    new InMemoryMessagingNetwork.ServicePeerAllocationStrategy.Random.Random(),
    Arrays.asList(new MockNetworkNotarySpec(new CordaX500Name("Notary Service", "Zurich", "CH"), true)),
    networkParameters,
    getTestCordapps()  
);
```

NB: getTestCordapps() just returns a `List<TestCordapp>` that I need for the test I am performing i.e.

```
private List<TestCordapp> getTestCordapps() {
 return ImmutableList.of(
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.template.contracts"),
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.template.flows"),
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts"),
    etc.
    etc.
)}
```

Step 3) Build your MockNetwork with your MockNetworkParameters object:

```
MockNetwork mockNetwork = new MockNetwork(mockNetworkParameters);
```

I’ve been using it for a few weeks and it seems to work.  If there is a better way please let me know.